# Meaning of 'non conformable' in R

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication, modulus

I have recently started using R and have come across matrices. I have a question to work out `x %*% y` but I get a error non conformable. I'm not sure what that means i have researched but have not come any closer. If I swap `x` and `y` to `y %*% x` then i get a answer. In general I am confused as to what the modulus is in the context of R. Any ideas? Many thanks.

```
x<-matrix(c(3,-1,2,1),nrow=2,byrow =T)
x
y<-matrix(c(1,0,4,1,0,-1),nrow=2,byrow = T)
y
x%*%y
Error in x %*% y : non-conformable arguments
```

Comment: This isn't an R question, it's a question about matrix multiplication.  Look up matrix multiplication in any linear algebra textbook (or just google it).  If you want to multiple matrices A and B, as in A %*% B, you need the dimensions to be correct.  In particular, if A is nxp then B must be pxm.  The "p" part is important.  The number of columns of the first matrix must match the number of rows of the second matrix.  Good luck.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about coding.

Comment: @DanY You are right, this question is about math, not about coding. Curious fact: the code runs with no errors, the dimensions are conformable. VTC.

Comment: If I copy and paste the code in the question into R I get no errors.  At any rate the number of columns on the left hand side of %*% must equal the number of rows on the right hand side.  In case of the code in the question both are 2 so it works.